# jQuery accordion - OnCollapse and OnExpand events

Tags: jquery, events, accordion

I have an accordion with single title like this

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion_acquired_services">
    <h3><a href="#">Acquired services</a></h3>
    <table id="tbl_acquired_services">
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

What I'd like is to bind an event on accordion open and accordion close...

Actually what I'd like to achieve is to do an ajax request that would populate the accordion's content each time it is expanded...

oddly enough there is no onExpand/onCollapse events

so far I have this

```
$( "#accordion_acquired_services" ).bind( "accordionchange", function(event, ui) {   
    $('#tbl_acquired_services').html('');
    //trigger ajax
});
```

But that triggers on both occasions, when it is collapsed and when it is expanded... how do I know which is which?

Comment: ok, found it. I just have to check if the accordion has active state class..like this: var opened = $(this).find('.ui-state-active').length;

Comment: Use the changestart event. See http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#event-changestart

Comment: Please read my question again. the problem is not when the event is triggered, but how to get the value if it is opened (expanded) or closed (collapsed). And I figured it out already ;)

Comment: Yes, I know, but I would do the ajax call before the accordion opens so the content is there when it is open. That's more of a cosmetic tip. According to the documentation you can access the new and old content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
var opened = $(this).find('.ui-state-active').length;
```

Answer (score 15):

Time changes and so is jquery. Copy/paste from  [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15297577/1356577)

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ activate: function(event, ui) {
          alert(ui.newHeader.text());
  }
});
```

another event:

```
   $("#accordion").accordion({ beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
        alert(ui.newHeader.text());         
     }
  });
```

[take a look at jQuerys docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#events) for more details

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 codes here to notice

1.Show
2.Shown
3.Hide
4.Hidden

So the code goes as below

```
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
 //on clicking the accordion menu
});

$('#accordion').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
 //on clicking the accordion menu
});
```

So now if we use Hidden and Shown we can trigger after the accordion menu content closes or open up completely

```
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
 //after menu opens
});

$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
 //after menu closes
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `change` event and the `active` option.  Like this:

```
$('#accordion').bind('accordionchange', 
    function() {
         alert('Active tab index: ' + $(this).accordion('option', 'active'))
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a old thread but this really helped me

```
$( "#Accordion" ).accordion({
collapsible: true,
heightStyle: "content",
activate: function(event, ui) {

  if(ui.newHeader[0]){

    if( ui.newHeader[0].id =='ID of h3'){
        // run code here
      }
    }

  }

 }
});
```

Doing this check if there is a new header object which is not generated when you close an accordion only when you open one.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15297577/2745343), jQuery doesn't expose the changes the same way as above.  This is a script I wrote that works with the most recent jQuery library that will grab the accordion's ID upon open and update the URL with that hash.

```
$(accordionSelText).accordion({
        activate: function(event, ui) {

            var accordionId=ui.newHeader.closest('.accordion').attr('id');  // Grabs the id of the accordion

            try {
                    if (accordionId) {
                        window.location.hash = accordionId;
                        console.log('Active accordion index: ' + accordionId);
                    }
            }catch(e){}
        }
    });
```