# Jquery accordion change event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, accordion

This doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#accordion").accordion({
                change: function (event, ui) { alert('test'); }
            });

        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>


    <div id="accordion">
        <h2><a href="#">Header1</a></h2>
        <div>
            <p>content 1</p>
        </div>
        <h2><a href="#">Header2</a></h2>
        <div>
            <p>content 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure and include the proper reference to the  [jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/) library?

try with this

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js'></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've JUST downloaded that JQuery file from the JQuery Themeroller site, so I didn't expect it to be the problem!

Answer (score 20):

The accordion widget does not expose a `change` event in recent versions of jQuery UI.

You can bind to the [activate](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate) event instead:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        alert(ui.newHeader.text());  // For instance.
    }
});
```

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer. I'll bet most people are running into jquery UI upgrade issues.